# How do I load symbols for concrete classes hidden by Interfaces in Visual Studio's Performance Analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio, dependency-injection, performance-testing

My Visual Studio (2012) solution currently has several concrete classes that are delivered via Dependency Injection. After running the Visual Studio Performance Analysis, in the Function Details view, I can click on Calling and Called functions and see all my code in the Function Code View except for code whose implementation is hidden behind an Interface.

The concrete implementations of these interfaces are in the same solution and the DLL's (obviously) and .pdb files are in the /bin folder of the application. In addition, the /bin folder of the application, containing the .pdb files of the concrete implementations, is explicitly specified as a Symbol file (.pdb) location (Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols).

Is there away for the Performance Analyzer to recognize and display code from concrete classes hidden behind Interfaces?